# No logro hacer que termine

Tags: c++, c

Se trata de un programa para que el usuario haga un pedido a la vez que se le hace un descuento dependiendo de su antiguedad Si son 5 años el el 8 porciento Si son 6 o mas es de 6 el descuento se tiene que mostrar el total como si fuera un ticket con todo lo que se cobro y se realizo Solo logro hacer que se devuelva al incio en las ultimas acciones Por ejemplo en la de malla cuando el usuario tiene 6 o mas de seis años ahi si pero cuando tiene 5 o menos imprime la siguiente opcion aun si el usuario ya decidio terminar  Ya no se que hacer pues ya reordene las llaves cambien los if por while agrege otros do y nada me funciono alguien me podria ayudar? quiero pasar la materia jaja

```
#include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    main()
    {
        int total,otro,opcion,importe,anios,pedido,malla=400,rollo=250;
        float descuento;
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("\t\t\Empresa Muros S. A.\n\n");
        printf("Que desea comprar?: \n\n");
        printf("1. Malla plana\n\n");
        printf("2. Malla en rollo\n\n");
        scanf("%i",&opcion);    
        
        
        if (opcion==1){
            printf("Cuantos metros desea comprar?");
            scanf("%i",&pedido);
            printf("Cuantos anios lleva comprandonos?");
            scanf("%i",&anios);}
            
            
            if (anios<5){
                importe=pedido*malla;
                descuento=0;
                total=importe;
                printf("Importe:%i\n\n",importe);
                printf("Descuento:%f\n\n",descuento);
                printf("Total:%i\n\n",total);
                    printf("Desea otra orden? (1.Si/2.No)");
                scanf("%i",&otro);}
             
            if (anios==5){
            importe=pedido*malla;
                descuento=importe*0.08;
                total=importe-descuento;
                printf("Importe:%i\n\n",importe);
                printf("Descuento:%3.2f\n\n",descuento);
                printf("Total:%i\n\n",total);
                    printf("Desea otra orden? (1.Si/2.No)");
                scanf("%i",&otro);}
                
                if(anios>=6){
                importe=pedido*malla;
                descuento=importe*0.06;
                total=importe-descuento;
                printf("Importe:%i\n\n",importe);
                printf("Descuento:%3.2f\n\n",descuento);
                printf("Total:%i\n\n",total);
                    printf("Desea otra orden? (1.Si/2.No)");
                scanf("%i",&otro);}
    
        
        
        
        if (opcion==2){
            printf("Cuantos metros desea comprar?");
            scanf("%i",&pedido);
            printf("Cuantos anios lleva comprandonos?");
            scanf("%i",&anios);}
            
            if(anios>=6);{
                importe=pedido*rollo;
                descuento=importe*0.06;
                total=importe-descuento;
                printf("Importe:%i\n\n",importe);
                printf("Descuento:%3.2f\n\n",descuento);
                printf("Total:%i\n\n",total);
                    printf("Desea otra orden? (1.Si/2.No): ");
                        scanf("%i",&otro);}
                            
            if(anios==5){
            importe=pedido*rollo;
                descuento=importe*0.08;
                total=importe-descuento;
                printf("Importe:%i\n\n",importe);
                printf("Descuento:%3.2f\n\n",descuento);
                printf("Total:%i\n\n",total);
                    printf("Desea otra orden? (1.Si/2.No)");
                scanf("%i",&otro);}
                
            if (anios<5){
                importe=pedido*rollo;
                descuento=0;
                total=importe;
                printf("Importe:%i\n\n",importe);
                printf("Descuento:%f\n\n",descuento);
                printf("Total:%i\n\n",total);
                    printf("Desea otra orden? (1.Si/2.No)");
                scanf("%i",&otro);}
            
     }
    
        while(otro==1);
    printf("Gracias por su compra");
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. 1. ¿Es C o C++? 2. ¡Las comas _existen_! Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta, y especifica tanto en el título como en el cuerpo de la pregunta cuál es específicamente el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías meter en el `if`, en el que analiza la variable *opcion*, todo el resto de `if`s en el que analiza la variable *anios*. Si te fijas, la ejecución de los siguientes `if`s va a llevarse a cabo, ya que el `if (opcion==1)` no introduce los demás `if`s, ya que cierras antes de tiempo el corchete. Te pongo a continuación como dejaría yo las condiciones:

```
if (opcion == 1)
{
    printf("Cuantos metros desea comprar?");
    scanf("%i", &pedido);
    printf("Cuantos anios lleva comprandonos?");
    scanf("%i", &anios);

    if (anios > 5)
    {
        importe = pedido * rollo;
        descuento = importe * 0.06;
        total = importe - descuento;
        printf("Importe:%i\n\n", importe);
        printf("Descuento:%3.2f\n\n", descuento);
        printf("Total:%i\n\n", total);
        printf("Desea otra orden? (1.Si/2.No): ");
        scanf("%i", &otro);
    }

    if (anios == 5)
    {
        importe = pedido * rollo;
        descuento = importe * 0.08;
        total = importe - descuento;
        printf("Importe:%i\n\n", importe);
        printf("Descuento:%3.2f\n\n", descuento);
        printf("Total:%i\n\n", total);
        printf("Desea otra orden? (1.Si/2.No)");
        scanf("%i", &otro);
    }

    if (anios < 5)
    {
        importe = pedido * rollo;
        descuento = 0;
        total = importe;
        printf("Importe:%i\n\n", importe);
        printf("Descuento:%f\n\n", descuento);
        printf("Total:%i\n\n", total);
        printf("Desea otra orden? (1.Si/2.No)");
        scanf("%i", &otro);
    }
}
```

Recuerda aplicar lo mismo para la otra condición de *opcion*.

Comment: Para que se formatee correctamente el código, coloca triples acentos graves (```) una línea antes y una línea después del mismo.

Comment: Gracias padelaina!

Comment: Padaleiana** :)